# How do I put videos in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter, firebase-hosting

I have a flutter app and that should be able to retrieve videos from firebase hosting. In addition, the app should also be able to add videos to firebase hosting and delete videos from firebase hosting. Hoe can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files to Firebase Hosting from a mobile app.  You need to use the Firebase CLI to upload files.

If you want your mobile app to be able to upload files to some storage, you should probably use [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).  It's meant for exactly this case.

Comment: You can put exabytes of data in Cloud Storage, so I don't think there's anything you could upload from a mobile device that will cause problems.